# Cannot read property postMessage of null while trying to integrate razorpay with angular9

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to integrate razorpay with angular 9 but I get the error cannot read property postMessage of null.  I have provided my code below

Code

````
      "key": ProviderCommonConstants.PAYMENT_KEY, // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
      "amount": "50000", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
      "currency": "INR",
      "name": "Acme Corp",
      "description": "Test Transaction",
      "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
      "order_id": this.order_id,
      "handler": function (response){
          alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
          alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
          alert(response.razorpay_signature)
      },
      "prefill": {
          "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
          "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
          "contact": "9745483240"
      },
      "notes": {
          "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
      },
      "theme": {
          "color": "#3399cc"
      }
  };
  console.log(options);
  let rzp = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(options);
  rzp.open();```

How to fix this issue ? Any help appreciated
````

Comment: Hi, could you please more details? For starters, at which line thw error is generated or thrown; or the logs when the error is thrownm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what may be causing this issue for you. Can you please elaborate?

Meanwhile, you can refer to a Razorpay Angular checkout example as well. https://github.com/ayush-razorpay/angular_standerdcheckout_example